# Adding extensions for MS SQL Server to PHP 5.3.9 ini file causes FastCGI Error on server

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, fastcgi

I am attempting to get a drupal site to work with SQL Server. I have followed the instructions outlined [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis/) to get PHP working. Then I downloaded the drivers [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20098) and unpacked them to my PHP/ext folder.  I then wrote an awesome php test page consisting of the following piece of code.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

opened up a web browser and pointed to the file localhost/phpinfo.php. All works wonderfully.

I then opened upt the installed .chm file that came with the php drivers for sql server and made the appropriate changes.

Based on the following from my PHPInfo page:

> PHP Extension Build   API20090626,TS,VC9

I added the following lines of code to my php.ini file

```
[PHP_PDO_SQLSRV_53_NTS_VC9]
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
[PHP_SQLSRV_53_NTS_VC9]
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
```

I then restart IIS and point back to my awesome phpinfo.php file and get the following:
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

with some lightweight recommended information on suggested things to look at for resolution.  e.g. file access, folder access.
There is no rights issue IIS_IUSRS has execute rights on the PHP/ext folder.

Anyone with ideas on how to resolve this?  Am I missing something somewhere to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You write that you add non thread safe libraries, but instead of `php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll` you add `php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll`. For IIS you should use nts libraries

Answer (score 0):

Most possibly MSVCP100.dll is missing

Answer (score 0):

Download and install:

Microsoft® SQL Server® code name ‘Denali’ Native Client CTP 3

from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26726